# Why is it possible to change chars in chars array, and impossible with char *?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

If I declare an array of chars (`char str[]`) I am able to change any of the characters inside.
However, if I declare of that array like this - `char* str="abcd";` its impossible to change any char inside.
why is that? shouldn't them both be the same thing?

Comment: Why do you say this is impossible? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char*` reserves space for the string in `Read Only Memory` so you can't alter it. Whereas `char str[]` is on Stack. Variables of type `char*` behave like `const` and hence you can't alter it.

Answer (score 12):

When you declare an array of characters

```
char myarr[5] = "abcd";
```

It's *your* array. The abcd letters are copied inside your local array and you're free to do with it whatever you want. A string literal in c++ (a string in "") is of type `const char[N]` . You can store a pointer to it

```
const char* p = "abcd"
```

Now, because p is const, you can't modify your string literal, which is good. Unfortunately, due to historical reasons, there exists an implicit conversion from a string literal to `char*`

```
char * p = "abcd"
```

In this case you can unfortunately modify the string literal, but ***doing so has undefined behavior***. Luckily, this conversion is deprecated.

Note that this is a unique issue with string literals, because it's the only type of literals that is an lvalue. All other literals are rvalues so there's no notion of modifying them.

Comment: I'll add that the reason you can store a pointer to a string literal is because a string literal (like any other array) can undergo array-to-pointer conversion, giving you a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Wasn't that conversion finally removed in C++11?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, it doesn't seem so: GCC 4.7 in `-std=c++11` mode doesn't consider it an error but merely issues a warning `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I'd be delighted to know that it has... but im not sure

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: C.1.1 states that it has been changed, example says: "char* p = "abc"; // valid in C, invalid in C++"

Comment: If I define: char * str=new char[5] I am able to change the chars, but if later on I'm assigning str, for example: str="abcd" its again unchangeable. so actually the 5 bits I allocated are still in the memory (not free) but the str is pointing to a read-only memory in a way that I lost my way to the "abcd" that is somewhere in the heap?

Comment: @user2162550: A pointer is just a pointer. If you allocate memory with new, then you do with it whatever you want. But if your pointer points to a string literal, then you cannot change it!

Comment: To clarify @ArmenTsirunyan 's point. If you have a pointer to a string literal you can change where the pointer points, but not the content of the string literal it points into.

Answer (score 1):

In the former case, you declare an array as,

```
    char str[SIZE];
```

the allocated memory belongs to your program and can be modified.

In the latter case,

```
   char* str="abcd" ; // str is a pointer to string literal, essential makes it a const char *
```

You are trying to write to a read-only memory location and the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an `array of char` = `char[]` this will reserve space on the stack containing the symbols you put in it + `\0`. As it is on the stack, it can be written to.
But something like `char *pc = "abcd"` creates a string "abcd" in the read-only part of your program. You just have a pointer pointing to the read-only string or rather `const char*`.